# Cannot convert undefined or null to object reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering about how to replace the item if it already exists inside state array and I got a great solution

https://codesandbox.io/s/4xl24j7r69

It works fine but my problem is I can't add a new item if the item doesn't exist inside the array I got an error `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Like this:

```
add = () => {
    let newUser1 = {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 3, // this is new id which is doesn't exist in this.state.data
      "title": "Two New",
      "body": "new data"
    }

    this.setState(prevState => {
      let newData = prevState.data;
      let user = newData.find(d => d.id === newUser1.id);
      Object.assign(user, newUser1);
      return { data: newData };
    })
  };
```

Comment: Try changing  `Object.assign(user, newUser1);` to `Object.assign({}, user, newUser1);`

Comment: @SrThompson its not working https://codesandbox.io/s/4xl24j7r69

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not adding the newUser to the data on state.

```
add = () => {
    let newUser1 = {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 4,
      "title": "Two New",
      "body": "new data"
    }

    this.setState(prevState => {
      const user = prevState.data.find(d => d.id === newUser1.id);
      if (!!user) {
        //Casting user to a boolean, if find did return a truthy value you add it to the data with map
        Object.assign(user, newUser);
        const newData = prevState.data.map(d => d.id === user.id ? user : d);
        return { data: newData }
      } else {
        return { data: prevState.data.concat(newUser1)};
      }
    })
  };
```

Comment: Thank you, now I can add item but if the item already exist I can't update it as before

Comment: Yeah, my bad, you did need Object.assign :D I was just fixing it. Anyway, you should always use that method as `Object.assign({}, ...etc)` because JAVASCRIPT